# Flutter: How to make a scrollable menu of the screen?

Tags: flutter, scrollable

I am working on a project but, I came across something I have never used before. When I searched about it I got confused with two ways backdrop and bottom sheet.

I want to know what is the exact way to do like the following pictures that I designed.

[image: normal way] [image: after scroll up the window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DraggableScrollableSheet widget